# Access is Denied Error When Creating Python Virtual Environment Over an Existing One

Tags: python, python-venv, access-denied

When I try `PS C:\Users\username> python -m venv env --clear` with another virtual environment in the same directory with the same name I get

`Error: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\env\\Include'`

The command works fine without the `--clear` argument. The other  venv arguments work fine as well.

I tried running the shell as an administrator but I still get the same error.
I am using Windows 10 and Python version 3.10.5.

Comment: Is the old virtual environment *active* when you try this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No. I made sure that any python scripts running in the background are also terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with `--user` option or close any python scripts running in the background.  you check the task manager and expand the python process if its active and close any scripts running.
Or you can just do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and collect all libraries in the environment and do `pip install -r requirements.txt`  to install them in another new environment but you need to remove the packages you didn't install in that environment from `requirements.txt`

Comment: At the moment the error doesn't cause me any issues I cannot manually handle. But I want to understand what's the problem causing the error. It is not just caused from that particular venv, any venv that I want to be replaced with the `--clear` argument gives back the error.